# Fullcalendar scheduler with allDay closed events

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Fullcalendar scheduler with allDay closed events

Curious if there is a way that when there is an allDay event, that I can change or swap out the entire view with some sort of *block* screen or view.  The benefit being that it'd lock out editing for users, but also it is (arguably) a nicer view for an all day event instead of just showing something across the top.  So instead of what we see in the first image, we'd get a view from second image.

The third image is just a regular view for reference.

Here is the code in my scheduler view:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tabSchedule">
  <div id="roomCalendar" class="calendar" ng-model="eventSources"></div>
</div>
```

And here is my calendar config:

```
$('#roomCalendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    eventClick: $scope.eventClick,
    editable: true,
    eventOverlap: false,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: $scope.dayClick,
    slotDuration : '00:15:00',
    slotEventOverlap: false,
    allDaySlot: true,
    resources: [{ id: 'room1', title: 'room1', eventColor: "#71A3C1"},
      { id: 'room2', title: 'room2', eventColor: "#45A43D" },
      { id: 'room3', title: 'room3', eventColor: "#FABE3A" },
      { id: 'room4', title: 'room4', eventColor: "#F8303E" }],
    events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
      callback($scope.eventSources);
    },
});
```

Thoughts?  Is something like this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

[image: default allDay view][image: proposed view][image: reference]

Answer (score 0):

I've found a work around that should accomplish what I'm after.  Still a work in progress... but I'm getting there using `eventAfterRender` and checking for an allDay status on the event.

---

```
eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view) {
    if (event.allDay !== false) {
        $scope.closedDayEventOverlay(event);
    }
}
.....
```

To clear out the overlay on days that do not have any events, we are hitting the same function but passing a null event.

```
events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
    $scope.closedDayEventOverlay(null);
    callback($scope.eventSources);
},
.....
```

Then show/hide the overlay:

```
$scope.closedDayEventOverlay = function (event) {
    if (event && event.allDay) {
        $("#closedDayEventOverlay").css('display', 'block');
        $("#closedDayEventDetails").text(event.title);
    } else {
        $("#closedDayEventOverlay").css('display', 'none');
    }
};
```

And the view:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tabSchedule">
  <div id="closedDayEventOverlay">
    <div id="closedDayEvent">
      <div id="closedDayEventTitle">Closed:</div>
      <div id="closedDayEventDetails"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="roomCalendar" class="calendar" ng-model="eventSources"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the end result.  Clearly some styling and positioning need to be applied, but I *think* this should do.  At any rate, if anyone else has another / better solution, I'd love to hear it.

[image]